# How to find out if there is something to read before calling while read?

Tags: bash, read, alpine-linux

I am very novice with scripting and I cannot figure this out. I'm trying to know if there is something to read and if not then

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/173779/77928. Do `read -t 0 ...` to set timeout to zero, and return immediately if there is nothing to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `bash` specifically, `read -t0` will return true if there's something to read or on stdin or the end of input has been reached and false otherwise.

```
if read -t0; then
  echo "there's something to be read on stdin, or end-of-file is reached"
else
  echo "there's nothing that may be read from stdin at the moment"
fi
```

Note that it will return true even if what's there to be read is not a full line or even a full character, and so a subsequent `read` may still hang waiting for an unescaped line delimiter.

If stdin is in non-blocking mode or if stdin is not readable, `read -t0` will always return `true`.

Comment: `true | that_script` => `there's something to be read on stdin`. No, there [isn't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33049/how-to-check-if-a-pipe-is-empty-and-run-a-command-on-the-data-if-it-isnt/498065#comment916641_497121)

Comment: same with `that_script </dev/null`, `that_script 0>/dev/null`, etc.

Comment: @mosvy, d'oh, good point.